# Divergence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{x}{k})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

I want to show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{x}{k})$, where $x\neq0$, diverges.

---

WLOG $x>0$, then I would simply opt for the limit comparison test which delivers:
$$
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\sin(\frac{x}{k})} ~\underset{\text{L'Hospital}}{=}~\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{x\cos(\frac{x}{k})}=\frac{1}{x}>0.
$$

So by limit comparison test the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{x}{k})$ have the same convergence properties. Hence, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{x}{k})$ diverges.

---

However, I was wondering if there is another approach which doesn't use limit comparison test? Maybe there is some clever manipualtion of the summand $\sin(\frac{x}{k})$?

Comment: You can also use the inequality (proven, e.g., by concavity) $\sin x \geq \frac{2}{\pi} x$, which holds for all $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: It only diverges if you set $n\to\infty$.